# React Navigation: Conditional Main Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a mobile application in which when the user opens the application if the user is signed in then he lands  on the homepage and if the user is not signed in then he lands on the sign Page and the user is signed in or not we store its information in the local storage

So my question is how to how to conditionally switch the application root navigator on the basis of value which in the local storage

Following is the code i am using in the navigator

```
const  BottomTabNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
   Home: { screen: HomePage },
   Library: { screen: LibrarePage },
}, 
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  activeColor: '#f0edf6',
  inactiveColor: '#3e2465',
  barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#694fad' },
});

const loginNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({ SignInPage, BottomTabNavigator });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer((AsyncStorage.getItem("IsUserLoggedIn")) ? BottomTabNavigator : loginNavigator );

export default AppContainer;
```

Above code is not working as the AsyncStorage.getItem("IsUserLoggedIn") is the async method so my question is how i can achieve the above scenario